# Creating a reflective surface without lighting effect

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, glass, reflection

Heyyo all :),
I'm a bit stuck, I'm working on a 3d packshot and I want it to have a reflection below the pack but without a visible surface underneath as the PNG image will be used in various places but can have a background except a reflection under it.

As you can see I've made the reflective surface no issue but its the white haze in the horizon that i want to get rid of :S
Cheers
Calpol

[image: Node set up]

[image: Packshot example]